# Why is Scrapy skipping through loop?

Tags: python, scrapy

This spider is supposed to loop through http://www.saylor.org/site/syllabus.php?cid=NUMBER, where NUMBER is 1 to 404 and extract each page. But for some reason it skips pages in the loop. Many pages. For example, it skips 1 through 16. Can someone tell me what's going on?

Here's the code:

```
 from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
 from scrapy.http import Request
 from opensyllabi.items import OpensyllabiItem

 import boto

 class OpensyllabiSpider(BaseSpider):
      name = 'saylor'
      allowed_domains = ['saylor.org']
      max_cid = 405
      i = 1

      def start_requests(self):
          for self.i in range(1, self.max_cid):
              yield Request('http://www.saylor.org/site/syllabus.php?cid=%d' % self.i, callback=self.parse_Opensyllabi)

      def parse_Opensyllabi(self, response):
          Opensyllabi = OpensyllabiItem()
          Opensyllabi['url'] = response.url
          Opensyllabi['body'] = response.body

          filename = ("/root/opensyllabi/data/saylor" + '%d' % self.i)
          syllabi = open(filename, "w")
          syllabi.write(response.body)

          return Opensyllabi
```

Comment: I have the feeling it's something with the `global i`. Can you change your code to use `self.i` instead? Otherwise, please post more code so we can see how you use this class.

Comment: No, it's not that. I tried self.i. It has to do with what's going on behind the scenes with Scrapy I think. I just use this class as a spider: scrapy crawl saylor.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
class OpensyllabiSpider(BaseSpider):
      name = 'saylor'
      allowed_domains = ['saylor.org']
      max_cid = 405

      def start_requests(self):
          for i in range(1, self.max_cid):
              yield Request('http://www.saylor.org/site/syllabus.php?cid=%d' % i, 
                    meta={'index':i},
                    callback=self.parse_Opensyllabi)

      def parse_Opensyllabi(self, response):
          Opensyllabi = OpensyllabiItem()
          Opensyllabi['url'] = response.url
          Opensyllabi['body'] = response.body


          filename = ("/root/opensyllabi/data/saylor" + '%d' % response.request.meta['index'])
          syllabi = open(filename, "w")
          syllabi.write(response.body)

          return Opensyllabi
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Can you explain why my way wasn't working?